# Why does the AngularJS default events directives use the `compile` method instead of `link` to read the attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was having doubts about how to implement a custom event in Angular, so I though, "wait, why not check the Angular default events directives, like ng-click, etc"?

So I found [this here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.7/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L3).

And here are the relevant bits:

```
['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    compile: function($element, attr) {
      var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName]);
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.on(lowercase(name), function(event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, {$event:event});
          });
        });
      };
    }
  };
}];
```

That's how each event directive is declared. Using the `compile` method.

But here I have my doubts. Why 2 different `$element` and `element`, in what situation those two are going to differ? Why use the `compile` method, if you can just use `link`? Why `$parse` if you can `$eval`?

I mean, I would just do something like:

```
function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on(lowercase(name), function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.$eval(attr[directiveName], {$event: event});
        });
      };
    }
  };
};
```

What are the advantages/differences of the Angular approach, vs my approach?

Comment: This provides useful information on link vs compile vs controller for angular function organization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post/24615123#24615123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular first compiles the markup and eventually creates a clone af the DOM-Element. This happens for example within an ng-repeat directive. After the compile phase the DOM-Elements are linked with a scope. So one should do tasks during the compile phase that are equal for all instances. In this case it is the $parse method that is equal for all instances.

The complie function returns a link function - otherwise there where no posibility using the precompiled informations. In the link function the event is bind to the DOM-Element. Remember this may be a clone of the original DOM-Element. e.g. we have $element and element. The second is eventually a clone of $element.

So your code is correct too, but the angular one consumes less ressources if there is cloning necessary. As for example with elements/directives in an ng-repeat.

Comment: Small plunker that displays this behavior: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5NDQ5e2Bga2h1XVMyB3?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Before angular v1.0.0rc1 this directive looked like so:

```
ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = valueFn(function(scope, element, attr) {
    element.bind(lowercase(name), function(event) {
      scope.$apply(attr[directiveName]);
      event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

#### This commit is part of angular v1.0.0rc1

[feat(directive): event now accessible as $event](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/1752c8c44a7058e974ef208e583683eac8817789)

#### This commit is part of angular v1.2.0

[fix(ngEventDirectives): parse expression only once during compile phase](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9a828738cd2e959bc2a198989e96c8e416d28b71)

As you can see, angular.js guys thought exactly like you do but eventually they had to make some little optimizations, it's all about efficiency.